# How to generate black and white pdf from sphinx?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I want to generate a PDF from sphinx that is only black and white. The standard `sphinx.sty` uses `\RequirePackage{color}` and `\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}`.

If I just remove `color`, I get a whole list of errors. I could not find any reference in fancyvrb's [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf).

How can I achieve that (without rewriting the whole `sphinx.sty`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the conf.py and add addtions to the preamble before the build with custom LaTeX, so that sphinx will render colors as black. For example.

```
latex_elements = {
# The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
#'papersize': 'letterpaper',

# The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
#'pointsize': '10pt',

# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
'preamble': r'''
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{black}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{black}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{black}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{black}\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
menucolor=black,
urlcolor=black,
bookmarksnumbered=true
}
'''

# Latex figure (float) alignment
#'figure_align': 'htbp',
}
```

This will change all sections and subsections to black and change all your hyperlinks to black as well.